# Fetching parent attribute for optional attributes in XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<client name="test">
  <projects active="true">
   <project id="pr1" active="false" />
   <project id="pr2" active="true" />
   <project id="pr3" />
 </projects>
</client>
```

For the above I need to fetch the project having active="true" in case it's been set at element level. If it is not then I need to go to parent element and fine the active element and check it.

We need to get all the project element hence this should return

```
<project id="pr2" />
<project id="pr3" />
```

I used the following but its not working:

```
//project/ancestor-or-self::node()/@active[position()=1]
```

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following XPath expression yields the correct result:

```
/client/projects/project[@active = 'true' or (../@active = 'true' and not(@active = 'false'))]
```

It translates to

```
/client/projects/project         Find an outermost element node "client", all its child
                                 elements "projects" and all child elements "project"
                                 of "projects".
[@active = 'true'                But only return them if there is an attribute "active"
                                 with a value "true"
or (../@active = 'true'          or if its parent has an attribute "active" with its
                                 value set to "true" 
and not(@active = 'false'))]     and at the same time there's no attribute "active" on
                                 the "project" element set to "false".
```

and returns

```
<project id="pr2" active="true"/>
-----------------------
<project id="pr3"/>
```

Or perhaps a slightly different variant makes more sense:

```
/client/projects/project[@active = 'true' or (not(@active) and ../@active = 'true')]
```

the result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
//project[(ancestor-or-self::*/@active)[last()] = 'true']
```